# Samba share is accessible but invisible

Tags: samba

we have two Ubuntu 20.04 LTS servers running. For both we applied identical samba setups except different share names and local paths. When we enter \IP.of.Server.1\ in Windows Explorer our share is visible and can accessed after entering User/Password.

For server #2 it's different.

When we enter \IP.of.Server.2\ in Windows Explorer a 0x80070043 error is thrown.

But, if we enter \IP.of.Server.2\share in Windows Explorer it's asking for password and everything is working then.

So it seems the share(s) of server #2 are invisible or it has a problem to list the available shares.

The shares are configured as follows on both servers:

```
[sharename]
   comment = xxx yyy
   path = /home/xxx/data
   browseable = Yes
   public = Yes
   writeable = yes
   valid users = schmaus
```

Both are fully upgraded to Samba 4.13.17-Ubuntu.

I already tried to temporary disable ufw to exclude a firewall problem and checked permissions. Both servers use the same username/password for the share and the user is owner of the shared folders and both have the same permissions.

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Hello. That is a Windows error number and not an issue with the Ubuntu OS.

Comment: On UbuntuServer2 run the command `testparm -s`and compare the output to the output of the same command on UbuntuServer1. Any differences especially in the [global] section?

Comment: Do what Morbius1 suggests, but I should point out that you cannot use 'public = yes' (which is a synonym for 'guest ok') with 'valid users'. Authentication happens before the share is accessed, so if a guest user (usually 'nobody' unless explicitly set in global) tries to access the share with 'valid users' set and the 'guest user' isn't in the list, the guest user will be denied access. I would also check that both machines are using the same version of Samba (is one fully updated and the other not ?)

Comment: Thank you Morbius1 your are right the "public=yes" doesn't make sense I removed it. The "testparm -s" command showed no differences between both servers

Answer (score 0):

Today the problem not longer persists. Accessing both servers now behave the same. I cannot say for sure but it seems rebooting Windows solved this strange problem. Yesterday when accessing Server #1 it took about a minute until the share showed up, today the shares on both servers are shown immediately.